# Java android Firebase JobDispatcher perform every 30 seconds

Tags: java, android

I want to create a task which should perform every 30 seconds, I tried below code but it doesn't work correctly it doesn't run every 30 sec,  sometimes is takes one minute , sometimes it takes 2 min and I have no idea what I did wrong. And this task have to work all the time , it should work even when the phone is asleep. I so I use a JobDispatcher  for do this.

I did this :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        scheduleJob(this);
    }

    public static void scheduleJob(Context context) {
        //creating new firebase job dispatcher
        FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher = new FirebaseJobDispatcher(new GooglePlayDriver(context));
        //creating new job and adding it with dispatcher
        Job job = createJob(dispatcher);
        dispatcher.mustSchedule(job);
    }

    public static Job createJob(FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher){

        Job job = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                //persist the task across boots
                .setLifetime(Lifetime.FOREVER)
                //.setLifetime(Lifetime.UNTIL_NEXT_BOOT)
                //call this service when the criteria are met.
                .setService(ScheduledJobService.class)
                //unique id of the task
                .setTag("UniqueTagForYourJob")
                //don't overwrite an existing job with the same tag
                .setReplaceCurrent(false)
                // We are mentioning that the job is periodic.
                .setRecurring(true)
                // Run between 30 - 60 seconds from now.
                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(30, 60))
                // retry with exponential backoff
                .setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_LINEAR)
                //.setRetryStrategy(RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL)
                //Run this job only when the network is available.
                .setConstraints(Constraint.ON_ANY_NETWORK, Constraint.DEVICE_CHARGING)
                .build();
        return job;
    }

    public static Job updateJob(FirebaseJobDispatcher dispatcher) {
        Job newJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
                //update if any task with the given tag exists.
                .setReplaceCurrent(true)
                //Integrate the job you want to start.
                .setService(ScheduledJobService.class)
                .setTag("UniqueTagForYourJob")
                // Run between 30 - 60 seconds from now.
                .setTrigger(Trigger.executionWindow(30, 60))
                .build();
        return newJob;
    }

}
```

Comment: 30s -> 60s -> 2m , etc , is what you'd expect for a `RetryStrategy.DEFAULT_EXPONENTIAL`. (or: 30s -> 60s -> 90s for DEFAULT_LINEAR). Are you sure your job is not failing?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas I want to do task for example when is hour : 00:00:10 next it should be 00:00:40 next 00:01:10

Comment: Yes, but you said that you have inconsistent times it goes off: 30 seconds, 60 seconds, 2 minutes. This is a pattern which is caused by the retry strategy, so I ask if the job is running *and failing*.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas so how i can creatw this task

Comment: is it good to run a service on every 30 or 60 seconds using firebase job dispatcher?

Comment: Hi @KrzysztofPokrywka I have same problem here. Can you please help me to execute task must be in every 30 seconds?